# why does Rails think 6,500 is greater than 10,000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seeded a database with four different values in the "result" column. They're supposed to represent dollar values but that's irrelevant.

```
10,000;  6,500; 1,000; and 0
```

In the model, I created this class method

```
 def self.result
    order("result DESC")
  end
```

In the controller, I called it

```
@decisions = Decision.result
```

In the index, it's listing them in the following order

```
  6,500;  
  10,000; 
  1,000; 
   0
```

When I switch DESC to ASC....

```
 def self.result
    order("result ASC")
  end
```

it reverses the order

```
0
1,000; 
10,000;
 6,500;
```

Comment: Are they text fields, I bet they are being sorted by ascii values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of that column? If it's a string then a string starting with 6 is "bigger" than one starting with 1

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the numbers as strings. Change the column type to `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Your column type is string, not number, they are ordered by string order.